# Why chapter label below the section label on new page even if by setting same spacing before title (use titlesec package)? 

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,papersize={50pt,70pt}]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\bfseries}{}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\Huge\bfseries}{}{0em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{abc}
\newpage\section{abc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This question is concerned with [Writing several lines before chapter title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18563/writing-several-lines-before-chapter-title)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a reason why

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-19pt}{0pt}
```

works as you'd like. It must be in the internals of titlesec.

The amount of backspacing must be -17.5pt if `\huge` is requested, -16.6pt with `\LARGE`. With `\Huge` the baselineskip is 30pt, with `\huge` it's 25pt and with `\LARGE` it's 22pt.

The sizes are actually obtained as

> `-(\topskip+\baselineskip-\ht\strutbox)`

where the `\strut` is computed in the font size. For example, with `\Huge` the height of a strut is 21pt, so the computation is

> -(10pt + 30pt - 21pt) = -19pt

Comment: thanks your explanation. But, why the section label doesn't need backspacing adjustment?

Comment: @dearmath: It's the chapter heading that skips down and backspacing of the right amount places it in line with the section label in the following place.