# Writing several lines before chapter title

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

How can I get the style like:

---

## chapter 1

bla bla bla bla ...

bla bla bla bla ...

---

A paragraph before chapter title --- this line is precisely on place where the first line of the other pages start.

the second line

## chapter 2

bla bla bla bla ...

---

## chapter 3

bla bla bla bla ...

---

This question is concerned with [Why chapter label below the section label on new page even if by setting same spacing before title (use titlesec package)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18561/why-chapter-label-below-the-section-label-on-new-page-even-if-by-setting-same-spa)

**Edit** (for Yiannis) Thanks. However, that isn't my demand. See below [image].

Answer (score 4):

Use the [epigraph](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/epigraph) package.

Edit:

To remove unwanted space use `\beforeepigraphskip=0pt`. Here is a minimal:

```
\documentclass{book}  \usepackage[papersize={200pt,270pt}]{geometry}
\usepackage{epigraph}
 \usepackage{titlesec} \titleformat{\chapter}{\Large\bfseries}{Ch. \thechapter}{0em}{} \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
 \begin{document} 
\chapter{abc}\beforeepigraphskip=0pt
\epigraphhead[20]{\epigraph{Paragraph an more writing}{a}}
```

% \tt
   % \meaning\epigraph
     \newpage abc
    \end{document}

Uncomment the `\meaning\epigraph` to see the macro for `\epigraph`. This method of debugging is normally quicker than reading through manuals for obvious situations like this.

Comment: @Yiannis: `\epigraphhead[70]{\epigraph{paragraph}{}}` coundn't put the paragraph precisely on place where the first line of the other pages start.

Comment: @dearmath It can be a setting for `epigraph` or due to `topskip`, try `\topskip=0pt` before you type the epigraph command. Even better post a minimal, if you still have a problem.

Comment: @Yiannis: `\documentclass{book} \usepackage{epigraph} \usepackage[papersize={200pt,270pt}]{geometry} \usepackage{titlesec} \titleformat{\chapter}{\Large\bfseries}{Ch. \thechapter}{0em}{} \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt} \begin{document} \chapter{abc} \topskip=0pt\epigraphhead[20]{ \topskip=0pt\epigraph{paragraph}{a}} \newpage abc \end{document}` How to choose the value of \epigraphhead's opt arg? http://i.imgur.com/x6Ggw.png

Comment: @dearmath Had a look at the package add `\beforeepigraphskip=0pt`.

Comment: @Yiannis: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Would you provide me an example?

Comment: @dearmath See edit.